# custom Activity animation in java code

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I want to use my custom animation when activity switch , I know this can be done in xml. But its important that its done by code, Because the position where it should be animated to is relative.

```
overridePendingTransition(slideLeft, slideRight);
```

the **slideLeft** and **slideRight** are animation defined in code. is there any way to assign the a **resId** for the animation defined in code ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no API for that. However I can suggest you a solution:

1) You may have to move your entire content view down to another layout.

2) Then set animation created in code in onCreate() to the content view.